# A hidden pun in さびしんぼう?

Tags: meaning

everyone,

I have recently discovered a weird monologue, related to the name of Japanese film さびしんぼう (Lonely Hearts), that suggests there is a hidden pun within it. That's what it said, I quote it below:

> 薬師丸に借りた「さびしんぼ 」って映画の中にさ、「 さ 」という字が「 び 」という字を 「 しんぼう 、しんぼう 」て 言いながらおんぶ して「 さび しんぼう ってセリフあったじゃん? おれなんかグッときちやってさー

It is clear to me what the title actually means (寂しん坊), but what is the pun of this decomposition? I see how 辛抱 has sense while one says it to his carrier, but not sure that's what was meant here. Does び mean 美? Or what would さ even mean exactly?..

Comment: I'm a big Obayashi fan but never considered that this wasn't a real word. According to [さびしんぼう (映画)](http://wpedia.goo.ne.jp/wiki/%E3%81%95%E3%81%B3%E3%81%97%E3%82%93%E3%81%BC%E3%81%86), he coined the word. It does show up in EDICT based dictionaries, but this might just be due to the popularity of the movie.

Answer (score 1):

> 「 さ 」という字が「 び 」という字を 「 しんぼう 、しんぼう 」て 言いながらおんぶ して「 さび しんぼう 」

寂{さび}しん坊{ぼう} and 辛抱{しんぼう} is exactly what you depict.
But, I'm sorry to say that 「 さ 」and 「 び 」 mean nothing but only have the sound of ***sa*** and ***be*** without any witticism being contrary to your expectations.